# Do we need a Turkish visa for a layover of 2 hours, from UK to Istanbul then to Egypt

Tags: transit-visas, uk-citizens, turkey

Because of the collapse Thomas Cook, we now have to fly from the UK on EasyJet to Istanbul where we have a 2 hour layover, then get Turkish Airlines to Egypt, our destination. Do we need a transit visa for this?

Comment: What is your nationality, British?

Comment: yes we are all british

Comment: You’ll have to clear immigration and collect your luggage before checking in for your onward flight. You may qualify for a e-visa https://www.evisa.gov.tr/en/info/who-is-eligible-for-e-visa/ depending on your citizenship. Have you checked with the airline/travel agent that two hours is enough time to make your connecting flight eg allowing for gate closure time and possible delay on the inbound flight

Comment: Notably, EasyJet will care if you are able to enter Turkey and will likely not let you board if you do not have the required documents. As far as they are concerned, your final destination is Istanbul.

Answer (score 2):

**[You will need](https://www.evisa.gov.tr/en/info/who-is-eligible-for-e-visa/) an [e-visa](https://cms.olympicair.com/timatic/webdocsI/spdbmainv.html)** because you will have to clear Immigration in Turkey to collect your luggage prior to your onward flight.

A two-hour layover sounds very tight to me. The minimum connection time [is said](http://www.connectionreview.com/blog/connecting-at-istanbul-new-airport-useful-information-for-transit-passengers-51) to be an hour  but that doesn’t leave much leeway. If you miss your onward flight because of even a short-ish delay on the inbound flight for example, you’ll be paying out for new flights.